# Limitations of linux Apache Web Server and how it is related with Processor and Ram

Tags: linux, apache2

How to Calculate the maximum capacity of a Linux Apache web server, ie) To serve maximum request parallel.

Or

To perform "N" request parallely, what is the configuration required?

I need to optimize my Web server so that it needs to response 1500 users parallel.

Comment: The first question is which MPM are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not answered so easily. It depends on the size of your RAM, your connection, CPU, the amount of memory each request consumes, the amount of memory the server side script (php/ruby whatever) consumes and the mode apache (mpm_worker, prefork, itk etc.) and the script execution (cgi, mod_php, fcgi, suphp etc.) run in. It also depends on the configuration of each of those modules, at least partly. Last but not least, a caching system like varnish can take of 90% or more of the load if used properly.

Basically try running a test from another (or 2, 3, 4) web server(s) and see if your system will serve the pages in an acceptable time.